# Change Variable Value on Each Click

Tags: vb.net

I have a variable "row" and i want on each btnClick to change its value like this: {1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,4..etc}

My solution is not working for each mouse click as i would like:

```
Dim row As Integer

Private Sub incrementVariable1(ByVal x As Integer)
    row= 1
End Sub
Private Sub incrementVariable2(ByVal x As Integer)
    row= 1
End Sub
Private Sub incrementVariable3(ByVal x As Integer)
    row= 2
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdScore.Click

  incrementVariable1(row)
  incrementVariable2(row)
  incrementVariable3(row)
```

End Sub

Comment: what a type of counting is this "1,1,2,3,4."

Comment: It's for a game and i have to have a value for the Rounds. It's like {1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1...etc}

Comment: how you generating `{1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,4..etc}` ??

Comment: what a type of counting is this; better to use random selection

Comment: i can help you, if  you give me the first 30 numbers in this series?

Comment: I'm not looking to crack my brain to come up with a formula for this. 
I'm looking for something simple like an array and each time i click it loops though the numbers or something similar. 
Just can't seem to find out how to do it.

Comment: Let's say that these are numbers: {1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,1}

And even if i found a soultion with a formula like yours, i would need a value for each position of each number cose the user will have to have a "delete previous row" and i will need a way to repeat that row and keep the game going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it quite worrying that no-one seems to be able to understand the question...!  Try this;

```
Dim RowData() As Integer = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4}
Dim Index As Integer
Dim row As Integer

Private Sub IncrementIndex(ByVal x As Integer)
    row = RowData(Index)
    Index += 1
    If Index = RowData.Length Then Index = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdScore.Click
    IncrementIndex(row)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank U Grim! It works just the way i wanted.

For others who will use this with Listbox for ex add : 
ListBox1.Items.Add(row) under IncrementIndex(row)

Comment: By the way I also find worrying that i'm staring at your code for 30 mins and i don't know when i will fully understand how it works ^_^

Comment: I can send you something with 2.4 million lines of code in if you really want a challenge :P

Answer (score 0):

I am totally confused about the counting `{1,1,2,3,4..etc}`, i thought it  was a typing mistake, but as a programmer i have to do this, take a look through my code : it gives the expected result

```
 Dim rows As Integer = 0
 Dim i As Integer = 2
 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
   rows += 1 ' Inrement rows by 1 in each click
   If i AndAlso rows = 2 Then ' true only if both i and rows are having 2
   ListBox1.Items.Add(rows - 1) ' display the result in the listbox in each click
   i = 0 ' 0 is assigned to i for make the condetion faulse for the next time
   rows -= 1 ' in this case rows is decreased by 1
   Else
   ListBox1.Items.Add(rows) ' display the result in the listbox in each click
   End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: It's still not what i'm looking for, but it's an interesting idea to practice a solution.
This is what i'm looking for and it has to be more flexible ..so i can change the values how i want {1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1...etc}